# when opening any browser in my pc, a pop-up ad website is automatically loading. How to solve it?

Tags: browser

When i open any browser in my pc, a pop-up ad website is automatically loading in those browser. I make restore setting in all browser. But still it is happenning. How to get rid of it?

Comment: Check to make sure you don't have any suspicious browser addons/extensions, and check your DNS settings.

Comment: I assume you have done a thorough virus scan. Are you opening the same home page in all the browsers on start-up? If so, check what happens when you open the same page in a new tab. If the ad appears, then it is associated with your home page, so change the home page. If all else fails, install an ad-blocker in each browser, but you should investigate other causes first, as you may have a malware infection.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems your browser has signs of having been hijacked. A solution to the topic of browsers would be to:

[Google Chrome]
1.Backup all bookmarks first
-type into the OmniBox (URL): chrome://bookmarks
-click on Organize and Export bookmarks to HTML file...

2.Completely reinstall the browser using the appropriate installation manager (Windows 7 names this as Programs and Features)

3.Restore bookmarks that you backed up by going to Chrome://bookmarks and clicking on "import bookmarks from HTML file..." and select the backup file you had created earlier

[Mozilla Firefox]
1.Backup instructions here: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/restore-bookmarks-from-backup-or-move-them#w_manual-backup

2.Completely reinstall Mozilla Firefox

3.Restore bookmarks

Viruses inject themselves into some main browser setting files when contracted, this is the simplest solution to your problem.